# It's mad hattering time

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash

We're participating in Winter Bash, earn **hats** by doing *stuff*. Add **hats** to your avatar. Turn off **hats** if you don't like them.

We have a **hat** leaderboard here: http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/worldbuilding.stackexchange.com

There is also an inter-site leaderboard here: http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard

Lets see how high we can climb ;)

Answer (score 2):

I got a hat...Warm Welcome.

Its not on the list...which drives me crazy cause I have no idea what I did to get it.

It is cozy though

Comment: That's one of the secret hats. It seems to be about up-voting a user that's new to the site.

Comment: That's when you check out [the list of this year's secret hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245170/157730). Note: list not guaranteed to be exhaustive.

Comment: Thanks for the link @MichaelKjörling