# Worldbuilding SE is participating in Winter Bash 2015

Tags: discussion, status-completed, winter-bash

Or, as they say, **bring on the hats.**

We participated in the annual Stack Exchange [Winter Bash 2014](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/609/29). Because everybody loves hats, we have decided to so again this year.

[Winter Bash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) will run from 14 December 2015 through 3 January 2016.

If you don't want to wear or see hats, there will be an "I hate hats" button in the site footer.

Have fun!

Comment: Can you summarise what this is about?

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Slightly dated, but [this blog post from 2012](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/) should get you started.

Comment: Here's hoping there's a tricorn out there with my name on it.